# Converting an ordinary differential equation to homogeneous form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following ODE:

$$2xy'+y=y^2\sqrt{x-x^2y^2}$$

We are asked to substitute $$y(x)=z(x)^a$$ and then to find a value of the parameter $a$ that would turn the equation into a homogeneous equation, but I can't figure it out,I'm stuck at this point:
$$y'=az^{a-1}z'$$
after plugging it and simplifying it a bit I'm getting: 
$$2axz'+z=z^{a+1}\sqrt{x-x^2z^{2a}}$$
Can't figure it out from here, would appreciate any directions, thanks

Comment: Did you try plugging in for $y = z^a$. Don't forget to differentiate it as well $y' = a z^{a-1} z'$.

Comment: yes I tried that, the square root seems to be bothering me the most, getting rid of it makes the situation worse unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2axz'+z=z^{a+1}\sqrt{x-x^2z^{2a}}$$
For $a=\frac 12$:
$$xz'+z=z\sqrt{xz-x^2z^{2}}$$
$$(xz)'=\frac {xz}x\sqrt{xz-x^2z^{2}}$$
Substitute $u=xz$:
$$u'=\frac {u}x\sqrt{u-u^2}$$
Separate and integrate.